# GestureDetector on tap is not triggring on alll the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

i am learning flutter and i just created an app that will update a counter variable when the user clicks on any part of the screen except the AppBar. However, the GestureDetector does not detect any clicks on the4 screen except for those on the text itself

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("i am a title"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          leading: const Icon(
            Icons.home,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: const [
              Expanded(
                child: Clicks(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Clicks extends StatefulWidget {
  const Clicks({super.key});

  @override
  State<Clicks> createState() => _ClicksState();
}

class _ClicksState extends State<Clicks> {
  int count = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => setState(
        () {
          count++;
        },
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text("total number of clicking on scren is $count "),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: See [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html). "If this widget has a child, it defers to that child for its sizing behavior." The child of your `GestureDetector` is just the centered text, and so it has taken on the size of that text.

Answer (score 0):

The `GestureDetector` will detect any gestures for it's *child* - in this case the `Text` widget.

If you want to detect everything, wrap the entrie Scaffold with a GestureDector.

In this case, you'll have to refactor your code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Clicks();
  }
}

class Clicks extends StatefulWidget {
  const Clicks({super.key});

  @override
  State<Clicks> createState() => _ClicksState();
}

class _ClicksState extends State<Clicks> {
  int count = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("i am a title"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          leading: const Icon(
            Icons.home,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              count++;
            });
          },
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text("clicked a total of $count times"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below changes :

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTap: () => setState(
    () {
      count++;
    },
  ),
  child: Center(
    child: Text("total number of clicking on scren is $count "),
  ),
);
```